# AdMob (urgent SDK update required)

Tags: android, admob

In my admob account i was getting the following warning message:

```
Starting March 18, 2013, we will no longer support ad requests made through AdMob SDKs released before 2011. Please upgrade to the latest version of the AdMob SDK here.
```

i have updated my AdMob SDK in my app that had the old sdk, but in my sites/apps page, next to my app name i have a warning as `(urgent SDK update required)` .

Has anyone experienced with the same problem?how can i fix it?
i'm getting adds fine in my app,my only problem is that i have this warning in my account

Comment: Are there still old versions of your app out there in use on user's devices, which have not been upgraded?  If your app had any real distribution, one would think so.

Comment: of course,there are users that haven't yet installed the update of my app(with the new sdk).So you think that maybe thats the problem and i continue to get this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will still get this message if you still have lingering users on old versions of your app that are making ad requests using old SDKs. If you already launched with a newer version of the Google AdMob SDK, you just have to play the waiting game for those users to upgrade.